# Owl Carousel 2, 8 items in two rows

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Is it possible to make the Carousel in two rows? I want images like below:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

& in 1 page only 1 to 4 images will be displayed due to width (or in small sized devices) so basically in one page it will be like

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

& clicking on next-prev controls others will be displayed. I hope I'm able to make it understand.

Comment: Don't know about owl carouse, but you can do that for sure with Swiper Slider: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.WKK24zt96Uk

Comment: Thank you so much @yavor.vasilev. You can also share this as an answer :)

Comment: Don't know about owl carouse, but you can do that for sure with Swiper Slider: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.WKK5fTt96Ul

Answer (score 0):

These steps can accomplish your tasks.
We can do it by

- wrapping the item class inside the rows and columns classes(can use either
  custom classes or bootstrap classes)
- adjusting responsive settings given by owl carousel plugins which
  will be located in js file.

If you have done something with code, please do provide code, so that we can point out the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for how to do it correctly with owl carousel. But I never did it. But I found a solution with slick caroussel (Slick.js). And I transformed what I needed with pagination, lines and filters

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would encourage you to add some code to your answer to increase its robustness. If you need additional help crafting a good answer, refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).